# Issues with warn command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I wrote this command to trigger adding 3 different levels of warnings but when i run the discord command on my server, the warning level stops after 1. any help would be appreciated.

```
if (command === "warn") {
    if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["Members", "Pro Team"].includes(r.name)))
    return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to do this. if you have problems with a member please message @GoldenCodex#0001");
    let warning1 = message.guild.roles.get("604071520381435954");
    let warning2 = message.guild.roles.get("604071671531307039");
    let warning3 = message.guild.roles.get("604071778809151680");
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    member.addRole(warning1).catch(console.error)
    if (message.member.roles.has(warning1)) {
member.addRole(warning2).catch(console.error);
    } else if (message.member.roles.has(warning2)) {
      member.addRole(warning3).catch(console.error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks, i assume the user is keeping the role `warning1`? If so, this means that the first if statement will always be hit, meaning that the second statement will never be reached. I would suggest trying to remove the `warning1` role once `warning2` is assigned.

On another note, you should check that the user has the role `member1` *before* assigning `warning1`, otherwise the user will always automatically be set to `warning2`

Edit: It looks as if you are trying to check if the `message.member` has the role of `warning1`, but `message.member` will be the admin (the one trying to warn). simply change the if statements to check for `member.roles.has()`

Eg.

```
...

if (member.roles.has(warning1)) {
    member.removeRole(warning1).catch(console.error);
    member.addRole(warning2).catch(console.error); 
} else if (member.roles.has(warning2)) {
    member.removeRole(warning2).catch(console.error);
    member.addRole(warning3).catch(console.error);
else {
    member.addRole(warning1).catch(console.error)
}
```

Comment: still gets the same problem

Comment: I think i have found your issue, you are trying to see if `message.member` has the role of `warning1`, but the message member will be the admin executing the role, i will update my code so that it checks the `member` has the roles